# Apple Script Calendar permissions with a locked screen

Tags: macos, applescript, calendar, ical, permission

at my work machine I've written an AppleScript that writes an reminder email for our group meeting. It is triggered by an event in Calender through *Open Application at time of event* and then reaccesses another Calendar in the Calendar app to get the next meeting date. At the end it sends an email with both event dates. And everything works fine when I'm at the machine and the screen isn't locked.

But when the screen is locked, the app asks for permission to access the Calendar (which it does not when the screen isn't locked) and if I don't grant it, nothing happens of course.

And if I then unlock the screen and go to *System Preferences > Security & Privacy* I see an app with a cryptic name (i.e. 737C530B-...D34B47.app) under the Calendar permissions tab. So this must be some kind of hashed name of my original app that I want to execute.

So, my question now is:  how can I permanently app my own AppleScript .app to the Calendar permission s.t. I don't have to grant them every time? Or how to I avoid this whole permission shizzle once and for all?

Edit: Here's the code snippet of the call to Calendar:

```
-- Date
set theMeetingDate to ((current date) + 1 * days + 3 * hours)

-- Get next meeting date
tell application "Calendar"
tell calendar "Reminder"
    set theNextMeetingDate to (start date of (first event whose start date ≥ theMeetingDate)) + 1 * days + 3 * hours
end tell
end tell
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers,

P

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

This link might help. Scroll down to the section to codesign your app.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914

Comment: Link not working.